# Linq query to select all records that have sub records that match all values in an array of values?

Tags: linq

I have a table that contains records that have a related table that may have multiple records for each of the main records. This is a table of flags. 
i.e.

`MyRecord can have multiple subrecords Flag1, Flag4, Flag7`

I am trying to create a Linq query that will return records that have all the flags I specify.

This is code of what I am trying to do

```
var flags = new List<string>() { "Flag1"};
db.Contents.Include(f=>f.Flags)
.Where(a => flags.All(b=>a.Flags.Any(f =>f.Name==b)));
```

The above almost works but returns records with `Flag1` along with records that have `Flag1,Flag4` and `Flag1,Flag4,Flag7`. I need to return only records that have the requested flags set.

Comment: Is the logic here that the record must have ALL of the flags array items and NOTHING else?

Comment: Yes, sorry if I didn't express that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var answer = db.Contents.Include(x => x.Flags)
      .Where(x => 
               x.Flags.Select(y => y.Name).Distinct().Count() == flags.Count 
               && 
               flags.All(y => x.Flags.Any(z => z.Name == y)))
      .ToList();
```